# How To change attribute in html elements in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

this is my asp codes in my page

```
<asp:GridView BorderStyle="None" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="0px" CellPadding="0" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="" ID="grdProducts" Width="100%" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeader="False" AllowPaging="True" DataSourceID="sqldsProducts">
         <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <!--begin col-lg-6 col-md-6 -->
                          <li class="list_item col-lg-12 col-md-12 portfolio">
                                 <div class="recent-item">
                                       <figure class="portfolio_1">
                                             <div class="bwWrapper touching medium">
                                                 <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("PImg") %>' runat="server" />
                                                  <a href='<%# Eval("PImg")  %>' runat="server" class="hover-zoom mfp-image" ><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <figcaption class="item-description">
                                                        <h5 id="PTitle"><%# Eval("PTitle")  %></h5>
                                                        <p id="PDesc"><%# Eval("PDesc") %></p>

                                                        <div class="go_link">
                                                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-small">Read More</a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </figcaption>
                                                </figure>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <!--end col-lg-6 col-md-6 -->

                                        <div style="height:20px;"></div>

                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
      <pagerstyle cssclass="pagination" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:GridView>
```

for example i want to add some css attributes for this code
h5 id="PTitle"<%# Eval("PTitle")  %>/h5 but i dont know how to find this id and add attributes

Comment: When do you want to add the styles? Server side or client side?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jQuery. Make sure you have jQuery embedded in your page.

Then you can access PTitle element using jQuery selector and assign CSS to it as follows

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $("#PTitle").css('background-color','#ff0000'); 
});
```

EDIT:
If you have **ASPX** page

```
<h5 id="PTitle" runat="server">Test</h5>
```

Then Code Behind:

```
PTitle.Style.Add("display", "none");
```

Comment: @NetProjectsIr, you can't, because it's just a template, not actual controls you can easily refer to... You'd have to override rendering.

Comment: this gridview return records of my products in my page the products title all have same id, and i want to change all titles text-align to right but i dont know how to find that id and change his attributes

Answer (score 0):

Depends on when you want to add the Styles. Here are few options.

If you want to add it in design time just add a style attribute as you would for other html elements.

```
<h5 id="PTitle" style="font-size:12px"><%# Eval("PTitle")  %></h5>
```

If you want to do it from code behind (server side) you need to add the `runat="server"` attribute to the element first. In this case you won't add the style attribute in design time.

```
<h5 id="PTitle" runat="server"><%# Eval("PTitle")  %></h5>
```

Then you can access this control in code behind using it's id as follows.

```
               for (int i = 0; i < grdProducts.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    HtmlGenericControl PTitle = (HtmlGenericControl)grdProducts.Rows[i].FindControl("PTitle");
                    if (PTitle != null)
                    {
                        PTitle.Style.Add("font-size", "12px");
                    }                    
                }
```

Or, you could use the Attributes property as follows.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < grdProducts.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                HtmlGenericControl PTitle = (HtmlGenericControl)grdProducts.Rows[i].FindControl("PTitle");
                if (PTitle != null)
                {
                     PTitle.Attributes.Add("style", "font-size:12px");
                }                    
            }
```

If you need to do this in client side make use you `JavaScript`/ `JQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's all I needed to solve my problem:

```
        LiteralControl litc=new LiteralControl();
        litc.Text = "<style type='text/css'> #PTitle{text-align:right} #PDesc{text-align:right} </style>";
        this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(litc);
```